# Oracle SQL PLS-00103 error INSERT NEW ROW

Tags: sql, oracle, row

This will be a long one and I am sorry if the question is not so interesting. I am just a beginner with Oracle SQL.
I am kind of new with Oracle and for now I try to make a script to add a new line in a table T_USER.

This is my code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON; --- IT WAS OFF BY DEFAULT

--- declare the variable

DECLARE

TUSERID NUMBER(38,0);
TORGID  NUMBER(38,0) := 'Write-the-Org-ID-Here';
TROLE   NUMBER(38,0) := 'Write-the-role-Here';
TQDL    NUMBER(38,0) := null;
TFIRSTNAME  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)  := 'Write-the-First-Name-Here';
TLASTNAME   VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-Last-Name-Here';
TEMAIL  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-email-Here';
TEMAILSUBSCRIPTION  NUMBER(1,0) := null;
TDIVISION   VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-division-Here';
TQNUMBER    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-QNumber-for-the-user-Here';
TACTIVE NUMBER(1,0) := 1;
TCREATOR    NUMBER(38,0);
TCREATED    TIMESTAMP(6);
TEDITOR NUMBER(38,0);
TEDITED TIMESTAMP(6);
TISDELETED  NUMBER(1,0)  := 0;
TLOGIN  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-QNumber-for-the-user-Here';
TSETTINGS   CLOB := null;
TDEFAULTINBOX   NUMBER(38,0) := null;
TACCESSTOPST    NUMBER(38,0) := null;
TTIME_ZONE  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) := 'Write-the-Time-Zone-Here';
TLIMITEDACCESS  NUMBER(1,0) := null;
TVALID_UNTIL    TIMESTAMP(6);
TCOMMENTS   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) := null; --- I think you can insert the number of the Incident here
TAFTERSALESACCESS   NUMBER(38,0) := null;
TSOURCE VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) := 'QCAT';

---- BEGIN

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(USERID) + 1
INTO TUSERID
FROM T_USER;
--------
SELECT USERID
INTO TCREATOR
FROM T_USER
WHERE LOGIN = 'Your-Q-number';
-------
SELECT  systimestamp
INTO TCREATED
FROM dual;
---
SELECT USERID
INTO TEDITOR
FROM T_USER
WHERE LOGIN = 'Your-Q-number';
 ----
SELECT systimestamp
INTO TEDITED
FROM dual;
-----
SELECT TO_CHAR
((select add_months((SELECT systimestamp FROM dual),1 *12) from dual), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ----"TODAY" ?????
INTO TVALID_UNTIL
FROM DUAL; ---- ADD one year to the currrent date

END 

----INSERT INTO

INSERT INTO T_USER (USERID,
ORGID,
ROLE,
QDL,
FIRSTNAME,
LASTNAME,
EMAIL,
EMAILSUBSCRIPTION,
DIVISION,
QNUMBER,
ACTIVE,
CREATOR,
CREATED,
EDITOR,
EDITED,
ISDELETED,
LOGIN,
SETTINGS,
DEFAULTINBOX,
ACCESSTOPST,
TIME_ZONE,
LIMITEDACCESS,
VALID_UNTIL,
COMMENTS,
AFTERSALESACCESS,
SOURCE) 
VALUES(TUSERID,
TORGID,
TROLE,
TQDL,
TFIRSTNAME,
TLASTNAME,
TEMAIL,
TEMAILSUBSCRIPTION,
TDIVISION,
TQNUMBER,
TACTIVE,
TCREATOR,
TCREATED,
TEDITOR,
TEDITED,
TISDELETED,
TLOGIN,
TSETTINGS,
TDEFAULTINBOX,
TACCESSTOPST,
TTIME_ZONE,
TLIMITEDACCESS,
TVALID_UNTIL,
TCOMMENTS,
TAFTERSALESACCESS,
TSOURCE);
```

I get the following error(s):

```
Error starting at line : 5 in command -
DECLARE

TUSERID NUMBER(38,0);
TORGID  NUMBER(38,0) := 'Write-the-Org-ID-Here';
TROLE   NUMBER(38,0) := 'Write-the-role-Here';
TQDL    NUMBER(38,0) := null;
TFIRSTNAME  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)  := 'Write-the-First-Name-Here';
TLASTNAME   VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-Last-Name-Here';
TEMAIL  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-email-Here';
TEMAILSUBSCRIPTION  NUMBER(1,0) := null;
TDIVISION   VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-division-Here';
TQNUMBER    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-QNumber-for-the-user-Here';
TACTIVE NUMBER(1,0) := 1;
TCREATOR    NUMBER(38,0);
TCREATED    TIMESTAMP(6);
TEDITOR NUMBER(38,0);
TEDITED TIMESTAMP(6);
TISDELETED  NUMBER(1,0)  := 0;
TLOGIN  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-QNumber-for-the-user-Here';
TSETTINGS   CLOB := null;
TDEFAULTINBOX   NUMBER(38,0) := null;
TACCESSTOPST    NUMBER(38,0) := null;
TTIME_ZONE  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) := 'Write-the-Time-Zone-Here';
TLIMITEDACCESS  NUMBER(1,0) := null;
TVALID_UNTIL    TIMESTAMP(6);
TCOMMENTS   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) := null; --- I think you can insert the number of the Incident here
TAFTERSALESACCESS   NUMBER(38,0) := null;
TSOURCE VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) := 'QCAT';

---- BEGIN

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(USERID) + 1
INTO TUSERID
FROM T_USER;
--------
SELECT USERID
INTO TCREATOR
FROM T_USER
WHERE LOGIN = 'Your-Q-number';
-------
SELECT  systimestamp
INTO TCREATED
FROM dual;
---
SELECT USERID
INTO TEDITOR
FROM T_USER
WHERE LOGIN = 'Your-Q-number';
 ----
SELECT systimestamp
INTO TEDITED
FROM dual;
-----
SELECT TO_CHAR
((select add_months((SELECT systimestamp FROM dual),1 *12) from dual), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ----"TODAY" ?????
INTO TVALID_UNTIL
FROM DUAL; ---- ADD one year to the currrent date

END 

----INSERT INTO

INSERT INTO T_USER (USERID,
ORGID,
ROLE,
QDL,
FIRSTNAME,
LASTNAME,
EMAIL,
EMAILSUBSCRIPTION,
DIVISION,
QNUMBER,
ACTIVE,
CREATOR,
CREATED,
EDITOR,
EDITED,
ISDELETED,
LOGIN,
SETTINGS,
DEFAULTINBOX,
ACCESSTOPST,
TIME_ZONE,
LIMITEDACCESS,
VALID_UNTIL,
COMMENTS,
AFTERSALESACCESS,
SOURCE) 
VALUES(TUSERID,
TORGID,
TROLE,
TQDL,
TFIRSTNAME,
TLASTNAME,
TEMAIL,
TEMAILSUBSCRIPTION,
TDIVISION,
TQNUMBER,
TACTIVE,
TCREATOR,
TCREATED,
TEDITOR,
TEDITED,
TISDELETED,
TLOGIN,
TSETTINGS,
TDEFAULTINBOX,
TACCESSTOPST,
TTIME_ZONE,
TLIMITEDACCESS,
TVALID_UNTIL,
TCOMMENTS,
TAFTERSALESACCESS,
TSOURCE);
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 65, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" when expecting one of the following:

   ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Thank you in advance for your help. I spend hours and this is the final result I was able to wrote, I can't understand what I do wrong.

Comment: Why did you tag an Oracle question with MySQL and SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a semicolon right after END.

Answer (score 0):

Your END is the wrong place. A unit in PL/SQL starts with begin and finishes with END. You can have more units, but in your case as you have only one BEGIN, so the last command must be an END;

```
declare 
-- declarantion of variables and cursors
begin
-- processing
end;
```

So, in your code

```
DECLARE

TUSERID NUMBER(38,0);
TORGID  NUMBER(38,0) := 'Write-the-Org-ID-Here';
TROLE   NUMBER(38,0) := 'Write-the-role-Here';
TQDL    NUMBER(38,0) := null;
TFIRSTNAME  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)  := 'Write-the-First-Name-Here';
TLASTNAME   VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-Last-Name-Here';
TEMAIL  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-email-Here';
TEMAILSUBSCRIPTION  NUMBER(1,0) := null;
TDIVISION   VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-division-Here';
TQNUMBER    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-QNumber-for-the-user-Here';
TACTIVE NUMBER(1,0) := 1;
TCREATOR    NUMBER(38,0);
TCREATED    TIMESTAMP(6);
TEDITOR NUMBER(38,0);
TEDITED TIMESTAMP(6);
TISDELETED  NUMBER(1,0)  := 0;
TLOGIN  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) := 'Write-the-QNumber-for-the-user-Here';
TSETTINGS   CLOB := null;
TDEFAULTINBOX   NUMBER(38,0) := null;
TACCESSTOPST    NUMBER(38,0) := null;
TTIME_ZONE  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) := 'Write-the-Time-Zone-Here';
TLIMITEDACCESS  NUMBER(1,0) := null;
TVALID_UNTIL    TIMESTAMP(6);
TCOMMENTS   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) := null; --- I think you can insert the number of the Incident here
TAFTERSALESACCESS   NUMBER(38,0) := null;
TSOURCE VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) := 'QCAT';

---- BEGIN

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(USERID) + 1
INTO TUSERID
FROM T_USER;
--------
SELECT USERID
INTO TCREATOR
FROM T_USER
WHERE LOGIN = 'Your-Q-number';
-------
SELECT  systimestamp
INTO TCREATED
FROM dual;
---
SELECT USERID
INTO TEDITOR
FROM T_USER
WHERE LOGIN = 'Your-Q-number';
 ----
SELECT systimestamp
INTO TEDITED
FROM dual;
-----
SELECT TO_CHAR
((select add_months((SELECT systimestamp FROM dual),1 *12) from dual), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ----"TODAY" ?????
INTO TVALID_UNTIL
FROM DUAL; ---- ADD one year to the currrent date

    ----INSERT INTO

INSERT INTO T_USER (USERID,
ORGID,
ROLE,
QDL,
FIRSTNAME,
LASTNAME,
EMAIL,
EMAILSUBSCRIPTION,
DIVISION,
QNUMBER,
ACTIVE,
CREATOR,
CREATED,
EDITOR,
EDITED,
ISDELETED,
LOGIN,
SETTINGS,
DEFAULTINBOX,
ACCESSTOPST,
TIME_ZONE,
LIMITEDACCESS,
VALID_UNTIL,
COMMENTS,
AFTERSALESACCESS,
SOURCE) 
VALUES(TUSERID,
TORGID,
TROLE,
TQDL,
TFIRSTNAME,
TLASTNAME,
TEMAIL,
TEMAILSUBSCRIPTION,
TDIVISION,
TQNUMBER,
TACTIVE,
TCREATOR,
TCREATED,
TEDITOR,
TEDITED,
TISDELETED,
TLOGIN,
TSETTINGS,
TDEFAULTINBOX,
TACCESSTOPST,
TTIME_ZONE,
TLIMITEDACCESS,
TVALID_UNTIL,
TCOMMENTS,
TAFTERSALESACCESS,
TSOURCE);

COMMIT;

END;
```